# how to make datetimepicker readonly in struts 2 compatible with ie7

Tags: struts2, struts, internet-explorer-7

I'm using the Dojo Struts2 datetimepicker, But textfield is editable with the keyboard. I want it in readonly.

I know that this question is answered on another thread, but the solution isn't compatible with ie7, wich is required for me.

The solution in the another thread is:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementsByName("dojo.test")[0].setAttribute("readOnly","true");
}
```

But, when I try that on IE7, I get a javascript error:

```
'document.getElementsByName(...).0' is null or not an object
```

I read about that, and chage it to:

```
'document.getElementsBy**Id**(...).0'
```

But I get another error: The object doesn't support that property.

Any suggestions?

---

I just wondering if I could change the template of the datetimepicker as I did with a simple Struts2 template... That will solve the problem

Comment: Try this `document.getElementById("picker1").setAttribute("readOnly","true");`, `<sx:datetimepicker id="picker1" />`

Comment: Or better solution with **[jQuery UI Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)** instead of deprecated `Ajax Tags`

Comment: About document.getElementById("picker1").setAttribute("readOnly","true"); was my second try. I get the error:  The object doesn't support that property. I think that it because the  sx tag transform into a <div> with that id, and a div doesn't support "readonly"

Comment: So, the solution in the another thread worked fine at other browser ( Firefox, Google Chrome, IE8, IE9) ?

Comment: yes, but I need to work on IE 7 :(

Comment: so, let's focus on get that on IE7, later, I will merge it with the other solution ;)

Comment: I just wondering if I could change the template of the datetimepicker as I did with a simple Struts2 template... That will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        makeReadonly();
    });

    function makeReadonly() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".calendar").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>


<td>
    <sx:datetimepicker name="up_bod" displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" cssClass="rounded calendar" >
    </sx:datetimepicker>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice Question.

Use following script. This will work in all browsers.

```
 < % @ taglib prefix="sd" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" % >
 <head>
   <sd:head/>
</head>

< script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('fromDate').children[1].setAttribute("readOnly","true");
};
</ script>

 <sd:datetimepicker  name="fromDate" id="fromDate" label="From Date" />
```

I hope this will work for you.